# Gem Koala Facebook API get_object request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I'm trying to get user's info via Gem Koala Facebook API with below code

`@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(auth_hash.credentials.token)
    profile = @graph.get_object("me")
    user.update(
      url: auth_hash.extra.raw_info.id,
      email: auth_hash.extra.raw_info.email,
      friends: @graph.get_connections("me", "friends"),
      birthday: @graph.get_object("me", "birthday")
    )`

`friends: @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")` works perfectly fine, I will get a list of friends.

However `birthday: @graph.get_object("me", "birthday")` will give me `type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message: Unknown path components: /birthday [HTTP 400]`

Things that returns arrays such as `likes`, `photos` works fine.

But strings such as `last_name`, `name`, `first_name` will give me the same error.

What can I do to fix this? Is there something else I can enter instead of just `birthday`

Answer (score 5):

Although it is not very well documented, I read the code of the gem.

[Here](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/api/graph_api_methods.rb#L37-L57) it explains how to do what you want.

You can do it like this:

`Koala::Facebook::API.new(ACCESS_TOKEN).get_object(:me, { fields: [:birthday]})`

This will return the birthday and the id of the user.

Comment: Thanks. Koala's documentation is not very kind when it comes to examples.

Answer (score 1):

`birthday` is not an endpoint like `friends`, it´s just a field in the user table. Same for `name`, `first_name` and `last_name`:

```
/me?fields=name,birthday,first_name,last_name
```

I have no clue about Ruby and Koala, but i assume you can add the fields parameter as object - this is what it looks like in the docs:

```
@graph.get_object("me", {}, api_version: "v2.0")
```

Source: https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Comment: Do you mean try like this - friends: @graph.get_connections("me?", "fields=birthday") ? For some reason it is returning me with id, birthday,first_name, last_name, etc etc

Comment: If I remove the '?' from 'me?' it will give me type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message: Unknown path components: /fields=birthday [HTTP 400]

Comment: well, then use the solution that works, and not the one that does not work ;)

Comment: What I meant was if I were to do just birthday @graph.get_connections("me?", "fields=birthday") it gives me  birthday PLUS id, first_name, etc. I changed it to @graph.get_connections("", "me?fields=birthday") and it returns birthday PLUS the user ID., lol

Comment: ok, that is weird. in general, you always need to define every field you want to get returned, by default you only get id and name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it!

```
rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
rest.get_object("me?fields=birthday")
```